# How to use Ant echo task to append to file when what I'm adding contains CDATA?

Tags: xml, ant

I need to create an Ant task to add lines at the start and at the end of .txt files.

I need to add this to the start of each file:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html"><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[
```

And I need to add this to the end of each file:

```
></ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><ac:structured-macro ac:name="anchor"><ac:parameter ac:name="">_GoBack</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I understand that I can probably use echo to append these to the files. However it seems that ![CDATA is how you call out the content to be added as code rather than executing any part of it in the Ant script. The problem is that the piece I need to add *contains* ![CDATA.

That is, I need a file at the end with the two lines above added to it verbatim. Can someone explain how to do this, if not echo, is there some other way?

I'm new to Ant but I've created build files with some other Ant tasks this week that work perfectly.

Thanks

**Update:** To elaborate, here's a simplified example of what I need as the result:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html"><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[

<!DOCTYPE html
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

</html>

]]></ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro><p>&nbsp;</p><p><ac:structured-macro ac:name="anchor"><ac:parameter ac:name="">_GoBack</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

What I'm creating are text files that create pages in Confluence. The opening and closing sections create an "HTML Include Macro" in Confluence that allows me to just use HTML, instead of the completely different system that Confluence uses. Between `<html>` and `</htmL>` in the above example is where all my normal HTML page markup lives.

If what I have here were in a .txt file put in a Confluence folder, it would create a Confluence page with a box, inside of which you can use HTML.

What my XML publication (from Oxygen) outputs is the part that starts with `<!DOCTYPE html` and ends with `</html>`

Comment: Don’t you want the section to add at the end to start with `]]>` so that you’re wrapping the file contents in a CDATA section? (CDATA sections start with `<![CDATA[` and end with `]]>`).

Comment: Thanks-- if I understand you correctly, then no. Please see above example I added though to be sure I'm understanding what you're asking.

Comment: So it's just that when I try to append those new sections using Ant, I run into Ant seeing parts of them as code rather than just appending them to the file.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that my first example somehow didn't have the ]] in it and my second example does. So yes, you're right. But the one including the ]] is the one I've been trying to add. If you know what I need to put in an Ant build file to accomplish that, I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not just the `CDATA` that will cause problems here, if you try to include any XML syntax in a section you just want to treat as text then your `build.xml` won’t be valid.

For example, just looking at text you want to add to the start of the file, but without the `<!CDATA[`. You could use the [`concat`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) task for this, and a first attempt might look like this:

```xml
<concat destfile="target.xml>
  <string><ac:structured-macro ac:name="html"><ac:plain-text-body></string>
  <file file="generated-doc.html"/>
</concat>
```

This isn’t valid, you will get an error (something like `The prefix "ac" for element "ac:structured-macro" is not bound.`) because Ant’s XML parser is trying to interpret the tags as part of the build file, not text data to copy into the target.

The solution is to *escape* the content so that it isn’t parsed as XML. One way to do that is to replace any `<` with `&lt;` and any `&` with `&amp;`:

```xml
<concat destfile="target.xml>
  <string>&lt;ac:structured-macro ac:name="html">&lt;ac:plain-text-body></string>
  <file file="generated-doc.html"/>
</concat>
```

You can extend this idea to content that includes `<![CDATA[`, just escape the `<`s:

```xml
<concat destfile="target.xml>
  <string>&lt;ac:structured-macro ac:name="html">&lt;ac:plain-text-body>&lt;![CDATA[</string>
  <file file="generated-doc.html"/>
</concat>
```

This can get a bit unwieldy, so a solution is to use a [`CDATA` section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA), so that inside this section you don’t have to escape `<` and `&`, they won’t be treated as XML markup:

```xml
<concat destfile="target.xml>
  <string><![CDATA[<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html"><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[]]></string>
  <file file="generated-doc.html"/>
</concat>
```

Note that the inner `<![CDATA[` is itself escaped because it is inside a CDATA section. Anything from the opening `<![CDATA[` to the closing `]]>` is escaped.

In fact it is the closing `]]>` that you need to add to the end of the file that causes the bigger problem. If we try to repeat what we did above for the end section it might look like this (including the start section, and where I’ve shortened the end snippet for clarity):

```xml
<concat destfile="target.xml>
  <string><![CDATA[<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html"><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[]]></string>
  <file file="generated-doc.html"/>
  <string><![CDATA[]]></ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro>]]></string>
</concat>
```

This is wrong though, since the CDATA section is closed immediately by the `]]>` that we want as part of the content. There is no way to escape `]]>` as part of a CDATA section. One way round this is to use the `&lt;` type of escaping instead of using `CDATA`:

```xml
<string>]]&gt;&lt;/ac:plain-text-body>&lt;/ac:structured-macro></string>
```

Note that we also have to replace the `>` in `]]>` with `&gt;` – normally you don’t need to replace `>`, but when it appears as `]]>` you do.

Another way round this is to break the `]]>` into two, each one being in a different CDATA section. This is a bit cumbersome, but allows us to leave the `<` in the rest of the string. This works by having one section that ends in `]]`, and then another immediately after that starts with the `>`. This would look like this:

```xml
<concat destfile="target.xml>
  <string><![CDATA[<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html"><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[]]></string>
  <file file="generated-doc.html"/>
  <string><![CDATA[]]]]><![CDATA[></ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro>]]></string>
</concat>
```

In this case, since the `]]>` is at the start of the content string, the cleanest result might be to combine the two escaping styles:

```xml
<concat destfile="target.xml>
  <string><![CDATA[<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html"><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[]]></string>
  <file file="generated-doc.html"/>
  <string>]]&gt;<![CDATA[</ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro>]]></string>
</concat>
```

The other issue you need to look out for is if the file content itself contains a CDATA section, since the closing `]]>` of that will close the outer section. If that’s possible you’ll need to filter the file contents to replace `]]>` with `]]]]><![CDATA[>`.

Comment: This was a tremendous education for me as well as a solution-- after just a little fiddling around and a few attempts, something I put together based on your final example now works perfectly. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

- for nesting `<![CDATA[..]]>`: the first occurrence of `]]>` will close the outermost `<![CDATA[`.

therefore, you need to use `<![CDATA[` to insert the characters `]]>` in two parts so that they are not parsed together causing `<![CDATA[` to end. for eg:

**`<![CDATA[`**`.. 
        <ac:structured-macro ac:name="html"><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[...
        .....` 
**`]]> <![CDATA[`**`]]`**`]]> <![CDATA[`**`>`**`]]>`**`</ac:plain-... 
        ... <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>`
       **`]]>`**

here `<![CDATA[ ]] ]]> <![CDATA[ > ]]>` will result in insertion of `]]>` into the txt file.

- for appending to the file, i think the easiest option would be to use the `header, footer` nested elements within `concat` . Check **[HERE](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html)** , it contains an example as well.